# How to produce digital pulses using 555 timer IC for stepper motor?

Tags: stepper-motor, timer, 555

[image]

I need to run bipolar stepper motor with 555 timer IC.

Is there any simple circuit to produce the pulses to rotate the stepper motor clockwise, anti-clockwise with the desired speed?

If there are lots of 555 IC models please mention the type or model number also..

And I also eager to know what is inside the IC  and its workings.

Can I use the above circuit?

Comment: This question is perhaps not what it seems.  Please read all of the existing answers before responding to it or asking followup questions.

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot more to controlling a stepper motor than simply producing the phase pulses.  You have to consider accelleration, decelleration, maximum speed, and producing the proper overlapping coil phases for the direction you want to go.  Once you have the pulses, these still need to be amplified to drive the actual coils.

Controlling a stepper motor is a great job for a microcontroller.  This can perform all the logic described above, plus can interface with the rest of the system to be told what the stepper motor is supposed to do.  Since the micro will only put out digital logic signals, no different from the 555 timer, you will need power electronics to drive the coils.  Depending on how the coils are wired, this can be a set of low side drivers or possibly H bridges.  Low side drivers can be done with discrete transistors pretty easily, especially at low voltage.  There are H bridge driver chips available that take digital logic control inputs and drive the coil lines accordingly.

Comment: can u give me the circuit for that. i already got answer from u regarding amplification of pulses(IRLML2502)... this time i expect u to give me circuit with any one 555 timer to control stepper motor...cant we accelerate and decelerate stepper motor using potetiometer. as i mentioned in my earlier question, i need to produce pulses at 5V and 5mA.. the maximum speed is 50Rpm(required in my application)

Answer (score 3):

The TE555-1 is not the analog timer chip that everyone is familiar with; it's actually a preprogrammed 8-pin MCU from [Talking Electronics](http://talkingelectronics.com/projects/50%20-%20555%20Circuits/50%20-%20555%20Circuits.html)

The confusion appears to be at least somewhat intentional on the part of Colin Michell, the owner of the website.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a 555 in combination with an L297 and an L298 to drive small (floppy-drive-sized and a bit larger) stepper motors.

While Olin is right about acceleration in medium to high performance cases, for comparably slow speeds and light loads you can just start issuing step pulses with the 555.  Microcontrollor sequencer solutions do have a lot of advantages, in cost, board space, movement profiling, and flexibility however some of the IC circuits can be advantageous for their ability to modularize potentially tricky parts of the problem such as PWM (chopping) current regulation - something that can be done in software, but may add a lot of complication to a learning project.

Topics like the pulse sequence for a stepper motor, internal workings of the 555, etc are covered in numerous references which any search engine will locate.  The question & answers format is better for the problems that remain *after* doing some research.

Comment: chria stratton: i have uploaded one circuit for Getting pulse from 555 timer. we can also amplify it. right ?  Then why cant we use the same pulse to run 12V and 1A stepper motor (torque 1kg cm)using this IC. my application is limited to slow speed (5-30rpm) but the torque i need is little bigger (1 kg cm)

Comment: and i thought the 100k pot in the circuit is to regulate the speed

Comment: @vijay I'm not going to say that circuit won't work at all - it's possible its leveraging some incidental behavior of the 555, but at the very least it is novel.  It is also for unipolar steppers rather than the bipolar type you requested.  Normally, one uses a pulse generator (such as the 555) to feed a logic sequencer which alternately drives one coil, then the other, then the first in the opposite direction, then the second all by way of a seperate dual H bridge.  The L297 & L298 pair are a classic way of doing this, a bit dated now but will illustrate even if you don't choose to use them.

Comment: How to use the above circuit to control bi polar stepper motor